# A very incredible question, Maven becomes naughty,selenium 4.0.0-beta-1

Tags: selenium

This is my maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But seleniu-chrome-driver in the local warehouse will always appear in two `versions 3.14.0 and 4.0.0-beta-1`

And when I

`ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

The imported one is always `ChromeDriver()` in 3.14.0;

But what I really need is `ChromeDriver()` in 4.0.0.1 beta;
Because only this version has `executeCdpCommand()` method

How can I force the use of `ChromeDriver()` in 4.0.0.1 beta;

Answer (score 0):

why are you using that dependency explicitly , you could use :

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>
```

it has `driver.executeCdpCommand(commandName, parameters)`  method

make sure you clean and rebuild your project.